# Recover oracle 10g database from old data files

Tags: oracle, recovery

I have an Oracle 10g database.

Unfortunately, our machine and system crashed and all the backups and Oracle archive logs, but we have old image copies of our data files and one of the control file (copy & paste)

How can I restore our database from these copies?

I tried to create a new database and replace the old files with new files, but I couldn't (I got message, we need to open the database with resetlogs, but we can't open it if we didn't make incomplete recovery)

Please help me

Comment: This is not an SO question. Try asking for help on [dba.se]

Comment: If you, at some point in the past, have had copied all the relevant files while the database was shutdown, it surely wouldn't complain about resetlogs. Since it does complain, either you didn't restore all the relevant files, or the files are corrupted. My first guess is that the files were copied while modified, hence they are inconsistent, hence you have no backup to restore.

Answer (score 1):

Try to "`recover until SCN...`" before doing "open resetlogs".

You'll need the online redo logs to perform this (not clear from your question whether you have them or not)

Comment: thanks for replay, but how I can execute this command (I don't have any database, I have the old files only), have I to create new database? if "Yse" how I can assigne the old redo logs file to the new database?

Comment: You should be able to execute this at the point where you were typing ´open resetlogs´. Recover until SCN would do the incomplete recovery...

Comment: I can't make recover until SCN, becz I don't have archivelog files

Comment: You'll need the online Redo logs and the SCN of the last checkpoint to recover until SCN.